# How to anchor to embed video

Tags: embed, vimeo

How would I create an anchor link from the Test text to the embed conten? I tried adding an `id="03T"` inside of the div within the embed comment block. However, when doing that I am unable to see the embed block in the visual editor.

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><a href="#03T" data-type="internal" data-id="#03T">Test</a></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Videos</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:embed {"url":"https://player.vimeo.com/video/25323516?","type":"video","providerNameSlug":"vimeo","responsive":true,"className":"wp-embed-aspect-4-3 wp-has-aspect-ratio"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-vimeo wp-block-embed-vimeo wp-embed-aspect-4-3 wp-has-aspect-ratio"><div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper" id="03T">
https://player.vimeo.com/video/25323516
</div></figure>
<!-- /wp:embed -->
```

Any ideas on what could be fixed to insert the anchor link and see it visible in the visual editor?

Comment: blocks already have an anchor attribute, have you tried using that? Otherwise if you want to make a visible clickable link then you should insert a paragraph or a button with text, and turn the text into a link to that anchor, simply adding an `id` to a HTML tag doesn't give it a clickable visible link and there's no reason the editor would change that. Note that if you modify the HTML directly there's a very strong chance your block will either fail validation, or it'll be regenerated based on the block attributes in the HTML comment and the ID will vanish

Comment: @TomJNowell Because of the embed element - I cannot see what the block for the anchor attribute (that's why I tried editing the HTML) https://wpmarmite.com/en/wordpress-anchor-links/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing the raw HTML isn't going to work, a worst case scenario is it fails block validation when reopened in the editor and your edits get replaced automatically.

Instead, use the `anchor` box under the advanced panel. Since the HTML of an embed usually comes from a 3rd party via OEmbed, you can **wrap the embed block inside a group block, and give the group block the anchor.**

E.g.

[image]

Note that "group block" is just a standard block of type group that comes with core. There are multiple ways to create them but they are just blocks that contain things, and can be found in the block picker/inserter. Any block that contains things/has children and can take an anchor attribute will also work. E.g. Column blocks, cover images, etc but group blocks are the simplest and least intrusive:

[image]

*Remember, when building things with lego bricks you don't get a chisel out and carve the shape you want into the brick, you build what you want out of many smaller blocks. WP blocks are the same, don't modify blocks, combine and use them as building bricks to create what you actually want.*

Comment: the name of the block is group block, group blocks just act as containers, analogous to a generic `<div>` tag, just search for group in the block inserter and add it, then put an embed block inside it